# Name of Formula $x^3+y^3=z^3+1$

Tags: analysis, terminology

I encountered the formula
$$x^3+y^3=z^3+1$$
with the condition, that
$$x<y<z$$
and wonder, whether it has got a specific name or whether it can be easily transformed into another well-known (family of) formula(s).

Comment: Hi T.K.. How did you come upon this formula?  The set of $(x,y,z)$ which satisfy your conditions is some subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$.  Your condition is cone-like, so the set $\{(x,y,z):x^3+y^3 = z^3 + 1\}$ is contained in a kind of cone.

Comment: In a programming class this formula was part of the task: Write a program, that calculates the first 18 sets of $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^+$, which satisfy the formula and the condition, ordered by increasing $x$.

Comment: @T.K.: I am not sure because I have yet to encounter equations personally yet, but I do run across things from time to time and this looked familiar when I seen it. I am thinking that this could be an example of a *Diophantine equations*, but like I said not sure so don't take that as a for sure. Might want to give this a look.
[1] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation)

Comment: It looks like the equation for a one-sheet hyperboloid.

Comment: @nightowl: I think, the term _Diphantine equations_ is the thing I was looking for. Thank you very much for this answer/comment.

Comment: @T.K.: Sure, your welcome.. Anytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath071.htm

There you will find $$(1\pm9m^3)^3+(9m^4)^3+(-9m^4\pm3m)^3=1$$ and another similar-but-more-complicated formula, also it says it is known that there are infinitely many such formulas, and it is not known whether every solution is part of such an infinite family.

Comment: Thank you for this link and for the formula. All elements of the set $\{(x,y,z), x<y<z:x3+y3=z3+1\}$ I already found, satisfy this equation.

Answer (score -3):

$$X^3+ Y^3+ Z^3=1$$ is the formula which is known as harder factor and yours is a distorted and conditional form of harder factor

If $X+Y+Z=0$ then $X^3+ Y^3+ Z^3=1$.

In your question $X$ is less than $Y$ and $Y$ is less than $Z$ means the minimum possible difference between $X$ and $Y$, $Y$ and $Z$ is $1$.
At the same time the minimum possible difference between $X$ and $Z$ will be $2$.

So there will in all the cases except $X=-2$, $Y=-1$, $Z=3$ where $X+Y+Z$ is not equal to zero then it must be that $X^3+ Y^3+ Z^3$ is not equal to $1$. So $X^3+ Y^3+ Z^3$ must be greater/less than $1$. As it is given that $Z>Y>X$ then $X^3+ Y^3$ must be unequal to $Z^3$. It means 
$X^3+ Y^3$ may be equal to $Z^3+1$.

In this way $X^3+ Y^3+ Z^3=1$ is related to the question asked by the poster

Comment: Maybe you want to give any reference to this? Searching for "harder factor" doesn't yield anything interesting on google & co.

Comment: I don't see how this is related to the original question. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: This is very wrong.  Among other issues, $X$,$Y$, and $Z$ are *not* integers!

Comment: @GlenWheeler: He's right, that $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ _are_ integers --- at least in the formula I encountered.

Comment: @T.K. Ok, but then you should mention this in the question *and* should not use $\mathbb{R}$. This is the set of real numbers.